# Plot of dshw does not place forecast data at the end of the sequence

Tags: r, forecasting

I am using forecast 7.1.  When I try to plot dshw it puts the forecasted data at the beginning of the graph instead of at the end of the training data.[image: Forecast dshw]

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like a new bug. I'll add it to the issue list at https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, [now reported](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/issues/295) on the github site for the package.

Here is a workaround for a simple example.

```
t <- seq(0,5,by=1/20)
x <- exp(sin(2*pi*t) + cos(2*pi*t*4) + rnorm(length(t),0,.1))
fc <- dshw(x,20,5)

tspx <- tsp(fc$x)
tspm <- tsp(fc$mean)
tsp(fc$mean)[1:2] <- tspm[1:2] - tspm[1] + tspx[2]+1/tspx[3]
plot(fc)
```